# NLP data drift for single observation

Tags: nlp, multiclass-classification, statistical-test, mlops

I am building a NLP classifier, Where I have `N` number of samples. My embedding size is `M`.
Thus I have have a matrix of `NxM`. Matrix is denoted as `X`. Now I have unseen single observation so it's a vector of `M` dimension. Vector is denoted as `x`.

I want to find if there is data drift (any type) between `X` and `x`. So I have following question

1. Is it possible to compute drift between a matrix and a vector ? If no, then what is work around?
2. Is there any data drift test which is not applicable to compute drift for single observation.
3. If I have to find JS Divergence drift between `X` and `x`, then How can be this done in python.